# SVN change WC url with local files unchanged

Tags: svn

**Background:** I have two similar project, `/dev` and `/online`(Actually, `/online` is a copied branch from `/dev`). I make developments on `/dev` and publish on `/online`

I want to syncronize all files from `/dev` to `/online`, including mods, adds and of course deletes. I cannot use `svn merge` as changes on `/dev` is really really large, and besides, `svn merge` can possibily failed during large merge while there is no way to continue merge.

I know it's a common operate to do `svn copy` and create a branch from `/dev`. But for some reason I insist on sync all files(Same svn-URL for `/online` and more important, easy to check all changes between publish versions).

That's why I need file-level sync.

**Current parctice**:

1. update dev and online WC, revert local changes.
2. rm all items in online WC
3. cp all items from dev WC to online WC (except externals)
4. commit all changes in online WC (except externals)

**Problem**: 
As I would cover all items in online wc with dev wc, step 1-2 sames really meanless for online wc. So I'm looking for a way to check wc url only and then I can reach my goal by simply:
 1. update dev WC
 2. change url of dev WC to online
 3. commit

Is there some way that changes WC url only?

Regards

Comment: There is `switch` command, but if bases of two folders are different then svn will merge the difference when you switch.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. But `switch` cannot achieve my goal as this command would add missing files back while I want my online WC to be files-sync with dev WC. In the other word, I would like to treat missing files as `delete`.

Comment: Did you try relocating?  So you update dev wc and then after you have make sure all are at head revision of dev then you click on the dev wc and relocate the url to online. Once you do that it should highlighted all the changed files and then you can commit.